# Eclipse Marker plugin Installation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to install following plugin:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/opensource/os-eclipse-plugin-guide/Marker.zip

from:

ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-plugin-guide/

But `help > install new software > local` results in this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/chiOX.png]
producing the following error:

```
No jar file found in marker
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unzip your marker.zip and from eclipse, select `File > Import > Existing project into Workspace`

Select the unzipped folder which will add a new project in eclipse. Click on that project, click

> Export> Deployable plugins and fragments > Install into host
>   Repository

It will install the plugin in Eclipse.